# Where TCP sequence number come from?

Tags: networking

I am wondering when I doing some example on Wirshark, where TCP sequence number come from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An initial sequence number is generated randomly on handshake, and the number is incremented accordingly for packets sent.

Comment: so it becomes form random number then based on this random number the packets will keep track on this number.

Comment: In the case of TCP, the number is incremented by number of bytes sent in the TCP connection.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but probably from the system included stack implementation of the OSI model???

http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/jun/7/understanding-tcp-sequence-acknowledgment-numbers/

Comment: There is no such thing as the 'system included stack implementation of the OSI model'. TCP/IP has its own model. Don't cite third-rate third-party sources when there are plently of normative references available, e.g. the RFCs. This one has some particularly stupid remarks.